# Keep a flat composition syntax with monadic chaining by composing partially applied `chain`

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads

Here is the usual nested code to create the right lexical scopes:

```
const chain = xs => fm => function go(i) {
  if (i === xs.length) return []
  else return fm(xs[i]).concat(go(i + 1));
} (0);

const of = x => [x];

const bar = xs => chain(xs);
const baz = ys => chain(ys); 
const f = x => y => [x + y];

bar([1,2]) (x =>
  baz([3,4]) (y =>
    f(x) (y))); // [4,5,5,6]
```

Without do-notation or multi-shot generators to simulate it there is no syntactic sugar to flatten the syntax. Let's try it programatically with Kleisli:

```js
const chain = xs => fm => function go(i) {
  if (i === xs.length) return []
  else return fm(xs[i]).concat(go(i + 1));
} (0);

const of = x => [x];

const bar = xs => chain(xs);
const baz = ys => chain(ys); 
const f = x => y => [x + y];

const komp = ({chain}) => fm => gm => x => chain(fm(x)) (gm);

try {komp({chain}) (bar([1,2])) (baz([3,4])) (f)}
catch(e) {console.log(e.message)}

console.log(
  komp({chain}) (bar([1,2])) (baz([3,4])) (x => [y => [x + y]]));
```

This only works if the monadic structure is nested inside the action `f`. The problem is jsut shifted into the monadic continuation.

But what about making this process implicit?

```js
const chain = xs => fm => function go(i) {
  if (i === xs.length) return []
  else return fm(xs[i]).concat(go(i + 1));
} (0);

const of = x => [x];

const bar = xs => chain(xs);
const baz = ys => chain(ys); 
const f = x => y => [x + y];

const komp = ({chain}) => fm => gm => x => chain(fm(x)) (gm);
const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x));
const infix = (x, f, y) => f(x) (y);

const chainAp = ({chain, of}) => f => g => hm =>
  chain(f(x => of(hm(x)))) (h => g(y => h(y)));

console.log(
  chainAp({chain, of}) (bar([1,2])) (baz([3,4])) (f)); // [4,5,5,6]

const g = infix(
  bar([1,2]),
  chainAp({chain, of}),
  baz([3,4]));

console.log(g(f)); // [4,5,5,6]
```

This seem to work for non-determinism but I'm not sure whether it works in other monadic contexts as well. Since the extra monadic context is the most minimal one (`of`), I'd say having an extra effect should be neutral in the same way `empty` is for monoids.

I called the combinator `chainAp`, because the mechanics resembles the applicative one. Has it a name?

Comment: I appreciate that the actual question here is *'Has it a name?'*

Comment: Couldn’t `chainAp` just be `f => g => hm => f(x => g(y => hm(x)(y)))`?

Comment: Searching for [`Monad m => (a -> b -> m c) -> m a -> m b -> m c` in Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Monad+m+%3D%3E+%28a+-%3E+b+-%3E+m+c%29+-%3E+m+a+-%3E+m+b+-%3E+m+c) comes up with `liftJoin2` and `bindM2`.

Comment: @cherryblossom I don't think so because it encodes static function application, which is applicative, i.e. it expects that `hm` is always passed both args. Consider the following monadic action assuming a maybe monad/short circuiting: `x => x === 2 ? null : y => x + y`. You cannot run this with your combinator or `LiftM2`, which is just `liftA2`, because calling the inner function depends on the prev value. This is the very feature monad brings to the table.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested solution in my original question is broken and there seems to be no principled solution to the problem of flattening the syntax of monadic chaining at all. At least none that doesn't leak into the calling side:

```js
// static function application

const chainn = ({chain}) => (...ms) => fm => function go(fm, i) {
  return chain(ms[i]) (x => i + 1 >= ms.length ? fm(x) : go(fm(x), i + 1));
} (fm, 0);

// value dependent function application (preserves the monadic prev-result/next-computation dependency

const chain2 = ({chain}) => mx => my => fm =>
  chain(mx) (x => chain(fm(x)) (gm => chain(my) (gm)));

// array monad

const of = x => [x];

const chain = xs => fm =>
  xs.reduce((acc, x) =>
    (acc.push.apply(acc, fm(x)), acc), []);

// MAIN

try {
  const r = chainn({chain}) ([1,11,2], [3,4]) (x =>
    x === 11
      ? []
      : y => ["" + x + y]);
}

catch (e) {console.log(e.message)} // fails with "fm is not a function"

const r2 = chain2({chain, of}) ([1,11,2]) ([3,4]) (x =>
  x === 11
    ? []
    : of(y => ["" + x + y]));
//    ^^ (A)

console.log(r2); // ["13", "14", "23", "24"]
```

Each subsequent invocation (`A`) of the partially applied kleisli action `fm` must be wrapped in a minimal functorial context. It works in this case and it should work for all monads but it comes at a price syntactical and performance wise.